# annotating a field from a related table based on another field on that table

Tags: python, mysql, django, filter, annotations

let's say I have two tables "Publisher" and "Book". Book is related to Publisher via Foreign-Key. To be able to reach book from publisher there is a related_name="Book" in Book model. How could I annotate date of a particular book to my query of publisher based on another field such as price of book?
What is in my mind is something like:

```
Publisher.objects.annotate(
     particular_date = F('Book__date' for which the price=150$)
).all()
```

I hope I was able to deliver the idea.

Comment: please let me ask: you would like to annotate book date based on price filter?

Comment: Yep. base on the price of that specific book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For complex annotations, you will need to specify annotation name as well, so in my mind it will look like this:

```python
Publisher.objects.filter(Book__price=150).\
     annotate(particular_date = F('Book__date')).all()
```

Comment: So I need to chain
annotate(BookPrice=F('Book__Price')).filter(BookPrice=150).annotate(F('Book_date'))
?

Comment: Thanks. Now that I know the answer it seems so obvious.

Comment: There are times when you could not use filter, in cases that you need to annotate different fields via different conditions.
say you need the publish_date of the book which its price is 150$ and the same time you need to annotate the weight of a book which its price is 100$.
In such cases it seems that filtering should be done using Case and Q.